# Looking for a popup webview for React Native that the user can dismiss (Android)

Tags: webview, react-native

I need to open up a web view that the user can easily dismiss.
It should be able to display a given URL, and have an easy option to dismiss (like an x button) - navigation buttons, should also be presented.

I looked up at [Awesome React Native](https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native) and yet couldn't find anything like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use React Native WebView component with a View wrapper to achieve it. Create your own MyWebView component like this:

```
class MyWebview extends React.Component{
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    this.goBack = this.goBack.bind(this);
  }

  goBack() {
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props) {
      return null;
    }else{
      return (
        <View style={[GlobalStyle.container, style.container]}>
          <NavigationBar  />

          <WebView
            startInLoadingState={true}
            source={{uri: this.props.route.url}}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

MyWebview.propTypes = {
  navigator: PropTypes.object,
  route: PropTypes.object
};

export default MyWebview;
```

And you can pass the url as param in your route function:

```
let passObj = Object.assign({}, Routes.MyWebview, {
  url: url
});
this.props.navigator.push(passObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [react-native-custom-tabs](https://github.com/droibit/react-native-custom-tabs)

It worked really well for me.